# Help with this demonstration about integrals and vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Help me solve this triple integral?

[image]

Comment: Did you attempt to solve this? You should explain where you get stuck so that people are better able to help you.

Comment: @1524 The only thing I have been able to do is solve the product point I do not know what to do.

Comment: Hint: There are three expressions that you could take as new variables $(u,v,w)$ to give *really* simple limits of integration...

Comment: What have *you done*, other than post a plea for help, and a link to an image, which has since been inserted into the post?  What help, exactly, are you asking for?  If you want someone to do-your-homework-for-you, this isn't the right site for you.

Comment: Hi Raul A. Hernandez and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand\diff{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}$
Let $\vec{a} = (a_1, a_2, a_3), \vec{b} = (b_1, b_2, b_3), \vec{c} = (c_1, c_2, c_3)$.

Your integral, expanded:

$$\iiint\limits_D (a_1x+a_2y+a_3z)(b_1x+b_2y+b_3z)(b_1x+b_2y+b_3z)\diff{x}\diff{y}\diff{z}$$

Introduce new variables $u, v, w$:

$$u = a_1x+a_2y+a_3z \in [0, \alpha]$$
$$v = b_1x+b_2y+b_3z \in [0, \beta]$$
$$w = c_1x+c_2y+c_3z \in [0, \gamma]$$

The Jacobian of the transformation $(x, y, z) \mapsto (u, v, w)$ is:

$$J = \begin{vmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\ 
b_1 & b_2 & b_3 \\
c_1 & c_2 & c_3
\end{vmatrix}$$

The Jacobian required in the change of variables theorem is the one of the transformation $(u, v, w) \mapsto (x, y, z)$, which is in fact $\frac{1}{|J|}$ (after taking the absolute value). Here we are assuming that the vectors $\vec{a}, \vec{b}, \vec{c}$ are linearly independent, meaning the parallelepiped is nondegenerate, so that $J \ne 0$.

The region $D$ is mapped to the cuboid $[0, \alpha]\times[0, \beta]\times[0, \gamma]$.
Using the change of variables theorem we have:

$$\iiint \limits_{[0, \alpha]\times[0, \beta]\times[0, \gamma]} uvw \frac{1}{|J|}\diff{u}\diff{v}\diff{w} = \iint \limits_{[0, \beta]\times[0, \gamma]} \frac{\alpha^2}{2} vw \frac{1}{|J|}\diff{v}\diff{w} = \int \limits_{[0, \gamma]} \frac{(\alpha\beta)^2}{4} w \frac{1}{|J|}\diff{w}$$
$$=\frac{(\alpha\beta\gamma)^2}{8|J|}$$
which is the desired result because $|J|$ is the volume of the parallelepiped spanned by the vectors $\vec{a}, \vec{b}, \vec{c}$.